# how to "replicate" a select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replicate

I need to do an insert into a table with the following SELECT:

```
select 1001, '2021-Q1', null, null
union 
select 1001, '2021-Q2', null, null
union
select 1001, '2021-Q3', null, null
union 
select 1001, '2021-Q4', null, null
```

I need to do this until I reach 2030. everything else is the same.

So the next insert would be something like this:

```
select 1001, '2022-Q1', null, null
union 
select 1001, '2022-Q2', null, null
union
select 1001, '2022-Q3', null, null
union 
select 1001, '2022-Q4', null, null
```

How can I do this without having to do it manually?

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: SQL Server, thanks.

Comment: I think that the process of selecting it via modified string is not ideal, I suggest that you should just use an incrementing ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SQL Server table-value constructor to at least make this a little bit easier - something like this:

```
SELECT
    1001,
    CAST(AYear AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + AQuarter,
    NULL,NULL 
FROM
    (VALUES(2021), (2022), (2023), (2024), (2025), (2026), (2027), (2028), (2029), (2030)) AS YT(AYear)
CROSS JOIN
    (VALUES('Q1'), ('Q2'), ('Q3'), ('Q4')) AS QT(AQuarter)
ORDER BY
    AYear, AQUarter
```